# Is there workflow API?

Tags: api, workflow

After a flow starts in SF, is there any API for external application to get/set the flow status?

Comment: Is your question about workflow rules or visual workflows (http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_vpm_implementation_guide.pdf )?

Answer (score 1):

In the whole process of workflow the records get locked in salesforce until it is processed .

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm

The outbound messaging is the only technique where in you can perform any action like workflow  in the salesforce.

You may use outbound messages than workflows in your scenario

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't a status as such, and there is no metadata Api which can be used to query a workflows progress once it has been triggered.
You can however use the debug logs (Setup>Monitoring>Debug Logs) if you want to follow the flow and see the actions being triggered.

What is your requirement ?

Comment: You can however extract the metadata describing the workflow itself into the eclipse force.com IDE. For every sObject, there exists an sObject.workflow file.